# SQL - Get difference on dates based on same column from different rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where it's stored all updates on form fields. I'm trying to build a query where I want to calculate how many time has elapsed between each update.

Here is an example of my table:

```
ticket,last_update,status
12345,2019-03-29 13:54:55.000000,canceled
12345,2019-03-29 12:46:20.000000,analysis
12345,2019-03-28 18:30:55.000000,canceled
12345,2019-03-28 09:31:20.000000,analysis
```

I want to check the diff time on status change between analysis to other statuses (each analysis has a subsequent status).

Example output:

```
First analysis: differente between analysis 2019-03-28 09:31:20.000000 and 2019-03-28 18:30:55.000000 canceled
First analysis: differente between analysis 2019-03-29 12:46:20.000000 and 2019-03-29 13:54:55.000000 canceled
```

Is possible to write a SQL statement to return this data? I'm stuck on this statement:

```
select ticket, last_update, status from history as h
where h.ticket = 12345
  and h.field = 'custom_field_a';
```

I would like to avoid write some code on backend to perform it.

Tried it using PARTITION BY:

```
select ticket,
       last_update - lag(last_update) over (partition by ticket order by last_update) as difference
from history as h
where h.ticket = 12345
  and h.field = 'custom_field_a'
group by ticket, last_update;
```

It should return 2 rows containing difference against analysis -> canceled, analysis -> canceled but i got 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select ticket,
       max(last_update) filter (where status = 'created') as created_ts,
       max(last_update) filter (where status = 'cancelled') as cancelled_ts,
       max(last_update) filter (where status = 'analysis') as analysis_ts,
from history as h
where h.ticket = 12345 and
      h.field = 'custom_field_a'
group by ticket;
```

I'm not sure how you want the differences expressed, but you can just subtract the relevant values.

Comment: @placplacboom . . . Precisely.  I don't see how you want the difference represented.  This calculates the values.  You can then readily take the difference however you like.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functionality, which takes the data from the previous row. This query below should be able to calculate the difference:

```
 SELECT last_update - lag(last_update) over (order by last_update) as difference
        FROM history AS h
        where h.ticket = 12345
              and h.field = 'custom_field_a';
```

/A

Comment: It's almost it. Check the example output, please

Answer (score 0):

You can join the relevant lines, like so:

```
  select created.ticket
       , created.last_update as created_ts
       , analysis.last_update as analysis_ts
       , canceled.last_update as canceled_ts
    from history as created
    left join history as analysis
      on created.ticket = analysis.ticket
     and created.field = analysis.field
     and analysis.status = 'analysis'
    left join history as canceled
      on created.ticket = canceled.ticket
     and created.field = canceled.field
     and canceled.status = 'canceled'
   where created.ticket = 12345
     and created.field = 'custom_field_a'
     and created.status = 'created'
```

Not sure how `field`  plays into it, it's probably a join condition on all joins as well. This will work if you have one entry per status, otherwise you'll get duplicate rows and might need a different strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the lag() window function to get the time difference between the two

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html

Edit you may want to use a CTE to filter your query first for the result you want.

```
with history_set as(
    select
        ticket,
        lag(last_update)
            over (partition by ticket order by last_update) as prev_update,
        last_update,
        last_update - lag(last_update)
        over (partition by ticket order by last_update) as time_diff,
        status
     from history as h
    where h.ticket = 12345
      and h.field = 'custom_field_a'
    order by last_update
)
select
    ticket,
    prev_update,
    last_update,
    time_diff,
    status
from history_set
where status <> 'analysis'
```

Comment: It's almost it. Check the example output, please

Comment: You probably need a `partition by ticket` in the window definition

Comment: Could you elaborate your comment, please? I've tried run with PARTITION BY but it keeps returning 4 rows instead of 2 @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: The entry displays the list of events and their time differences, do you want 2 events combined into 1 row - what do you do if more or less than 2 rows exist?

Comment: Also, for your information the partition by is to ensure that different tickets are not grouped together (they can not be in your query but it's good practice to do this)